# Is using the CSN of a mifare desfire EV2 safe?

Tags: encryption, authentication, rfid, nfc

From what I know, Mifare Classic cards are easy to [copy/clone](http://cs.ru.nl/%7Erverdult/Ciphertext-only_Cryptanalysis_on_Hardened_Mifare_Classic_Cards-CCS_2015.pdf) using a device such as a flipperzero, and it has to do with authentication using the CSN (card serial number)

However, let's say that a system has 2 kinds of readers, a reader that reads CSN for authentication and a reader that reads the actual encrypted data in the card for authentication.

Sure EV2 is pretty safe if one used the encrypted data, but what if one needed cross-compatibility with old readers, that do not support reading the encrypted data (an HID R10 for example) but instead would rely on the CSN?

How hard is it to copy the CSN onto another card (not the encrypted data of the EV2, JUST the CSN) and use that on the old readers for authentication?

Comment: It depends entirely on the capabilities of the device you are copying onto. Getting the CSN, as you say, is trivial. Whether or not you can override the CSN on another device depends on whether that device allows it.

Comment: @schroeder Thank you for your reply, lets say for example I was able to copy the CSN onto a card like those: [link](https://lab401.com/products/desfire-compatible-emulator-uid-modifiable) That would mean that the HID R10 readers for example, would represent a security risk using the CSN of the mifare ev2 for authentication? or is the CSN encoded on the Mifare cards?